# Guess the average with 4 players

Tags: game-theory

Suppose we have $4$ players. Each player picks a real number between $0$ and $100$ (both included). The player with the number closest to the average of the $4$ numbers picked wins. If there is a tie, the prize is split evenly. My goal is to find the Nash Equilibrium.

Players: $4$

Strategies: $S_{i}\in [0, 100]$ for $i=1, 2, 3, 4$

Payoffs: {$1, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{4}, 0$}

I let $c=\frac{n_{1}+n_{2}+n_{3}+n_{4}}{4}$ where $n_{i}$ are the numbers picked by the players respectively.

As player $1$, my goal is to minimize the following function:

$|c-n_{1}|=|\frac{-3n_{1}+n_{2}+n_{3}+n_{4}}{4}|$ and it is minimized at $n_{1}=\frac{n_{2}+n_{3}+n_{4}}{3}$

The same approach can be taken for any player $i$. How do I go about finding the Nash Equilibrium?

Comment: I suspect there is more than one Nash equilibrium, for example when they all choose the same number

Comment: @Henry, I was thinking about that scenario. Since we are talking about real numbers here, there are infinite Nash Equilibria. Is there any method to go about proving these NEs or should I just take cases and show that they are indeed NEs?

Comment: @Sadem Consider your constraint $n_1 = (n_2 + n_3 + n_4)/3$ and apply it to the other players. This gives 4 linear equations in 4 unknowns. These can be solved for constraints on the possible choices of $n_i$. Then look at strategies that satisfy those constraints and verify which ones are equilibria.

Comment: @eyeballfrog, thank you! I just did that and found $n_{1}=n_{2}=n_{3}=n_{4}$ as you previously mentioned! My approach now should be to show that this is a Nash Equilibrium. Since it is derived from individual maximization, I don't need to test other cases, it is the unique NE if it is a NE, right?